# Vim ctags, Ctrl + click makes mouse scroll misbehave

Tags: php, vim, mousewheel, ctags

It's weird behavior, but I isolated the problem.

I am using ctags with PHP.

If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (follow) a token, mouse scrolls normally when activated in the following document.

Now, if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd> the token, then the next document is opened with each scroll "delta" equivalent to a <kbd>Page Down</kbd> or <kbd>Page Up</kbd>.

(meaning that page scrolls too much faster).

Anyone ever seen this before ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you happen to be running Vim in the rxvt-unicode terminal?

Comment: I think I'm not. I'm using regular Gnome terminal, in Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: same problem with gnome-terminal in ubuntu 12.04, is this reported somewhere yet?

Comment: I didn't report it nor find any at the time. Seems like a ctags problem. Are you using vim 7.4 ?

Comment: (you should use `@gokcehan` in your comment so I get a notification). I have this problem on two different machines with vim 7.3 and 7.4 with blank `vimrc` and only setting `set mouse=a`. Why do you say this is a ctags problem?

Comment: Ok @gokcehan. I wondered that because vim 7.4 has a thousand patches and this could be remediated from these.

Comment: Unfortunately @gokcehan I changed my gear and I currently use phpStorm with Vim keymap, so that is not a current issue therefore my lack of research.

Comment: And I got notified of your reply by the top left StackExchange box even without your @Niloct notification =)

Comment: It's because this is your question so you get notifications for every comment even without `@Niloct`. I was going to report this as a bug but I need to get subscribed to vim mailing lists for that and I feel quite lazy about it. Anyways thanks for your reply, I hope I grow up and switch to a real IDE someday like you did =)

Comment: I see @gokcehan, thanks! I still use vim remotely and for some things in my machine =)

Comment: This problem still exists in ubuntu 16.04, vim 7.4 (2013 Aug 10 code)... Currently, the only work-around is additional left mouse click somewhere in the new window.

Comment: Hi @anishsane. I still use vim a lot, but now I mostly use `g]` since it lists all possible jumps for a single tag. It´s far better than `Ctrl+click`. Nevertheless now I'm not using Linux on my desktop. Also, you can check out Vim 8.0 which came out this week!

Comment: `ctrl+click` also shows me the list of jumps. In short, `^]`, `g]` and `ctrl+click` all show me a list of tag jumps... And yes, I haven't installed vim8 yet :-( I was waiting for it...

Comment: Ah in `iterm` on mac that doesn't work, and I could not recall if it did back then :) I'm upgrading my vim right now!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using vim in tmux. Adding

```
set ttymouse=xterm2
```

in .vimrc solved this problem.